# css for a content page is converting to "QuirkMode" in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

hey guys, i have a page "shopingcart.aspx" in one of the contentplaceholder of master page, now when i load this page css is render just fine, but when i go to this page by postback e.g "shopingcart.aspx?itemid=1" then the css is rendering like quirkmode. All the content of the table are showin' bigger, any one out there faced this kind a problem ? any idea guys please help me out here..

Comment: @IrishChietain: hey,i figured it out, actually theres little javascript code in codebehind that shows a alert message using response.write(). When removed that Response.write() its working just fine, Actually "Response.Write" will always output the string/text
before the page's html content, this will make the page output not a valid
html/xhtml document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Response.write()` whereever you are using it with `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "your script")`.

`Response.Write` has no place in web forms based ASP.NET.  Anything that you `response.write` will get injected in the response before the rest of the page.  Look at View Source on the rendered page and you will see that your `<script>` tag appears before the `<html>` tag (which should be the first one).